# Vagrant synced folders (smb) on hyper-v with internal switch

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I am trying to provision a VM through vagrant but can't figure out how to get synced folders (smb) working when I use an internal switch.

I use hyper-v as hypervisor and one of the limitations is that a static IP for the VM can not be enforced from vagrant. I have a script to set up a static IPv4 in the guest machine that runs as `provisioning` step.

The problem is that synced folders are mounted *before* provisioning kicks off. At that moment the host network is unreachable, mounting fails and `vagrant up` ends with an error.

A possible solution that I thought of (but didn't work) was to figure out if the VM has been provisioned yet and enable the synced folder in that case. I was hoping the plugin `vagrant-reload` could have helped me but the synced folders are not re-evaluated again.

Any one that can give me some pointers?

My machine configuration:

- Host: Windows 10
- Guest: CentOS7
- Hypervisor: Hyper-V

My vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    provisioned = File.exist?(".vagrant/machines/default/hyperv/action_provision")

    config.vm.box = "centos/7"
    config.vm.network "private_network", bridge: "Vagrant"

    config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/shared", type: "smb",
        disabled: provisioned == false,
        smb_host: "10.0.0.3",
        smb_username: "vagrant", 
        smb_password: "vagrant",
        mount_options: ["username=vagrant","password=vagrant"]

    config.vm.provision "file",
        source: "./provisioning",
        destination: "/tmp/provisioning" 

    config.vm.provision "static-ip",
        type: "shell",
        inline: "/bin/sh /tmp/provisioning/static-ip.sh"

    config.vm.provision :reload

    config.vm.provider 'hyperv' do |hv|
        hv.ip_address_timeout = 240
        hv.cpus = 2
        hv.memory = "2048"
        hv.vmname = "centos"
    end
end
```

**Please note**: I got this working when I use the Default switch or an External switch. But I want to get this working with an internal switch to test a scenario with a VM that never connects to the internet.